# How can I diminish bank conflicts in this code?

Tags: cuda, bank-conflict

This piece of CUDA code reports lots of bank conflicts when analysed by Nsight. The first snippet contains the constants definition and kernel call:

```
// Front update related constants
#define NDEQUES 6
#define FRONT_UPDATE_THREADS 480
#define BVTT_DEQUE_SIZE 500000
#define FRONT_DEQUE_SIZE 5000000
#define FRONT_UPDATE_SHARED_SIZE FRONT_UPDATE_THREADS*2

updateFront<OBBNode , OBB , BVTT_DEQUE_SIZE , FRONT_DEQUE_SIZE , FRONT_UPDATE_THREADS>
    <<<NDEQUES, FRONT_UPDATE_THREADS>>>
    (d_aFront , d_aOutputFront , d_aiFrontCounts , d_aWorkQueues , d_aiWorkQueueCounts , d_collisionPairs ,
    d_collisionPairIndex , obbTree1 , d_triIndices1);
```

The second snippet has the kernel code:

```
template<typename TreeNode , typename BV , unsigned int uiGlobalWorkQueueCapacity , unsigned int uiGlobalFrontCapacity ,
unsigned int uiNThreads>
void __global__ updateFront(Int2Array *aFront , Int2Array *aOutputFront , int *aiFrontIdx , Int2Array *aWork_queues ,
int* aiWork_queue_counts , int2 *auiCollisionPairs , unsigned int *uiCollisionPairsIdx , const TreeNode* tree ,
uint3 *aTriIndices)
{
__shared__ unsigned int uiInputFrontIdx;
__shared__ unsigned int uiOutputFrontIdx;
__shared__ unsigned int uiWorkQueueIdx;

__shared__ int          iLeafLeafOffset;
__shared__ int          iNode0GreaterOffset;
__shared__ int          iNode1GreaterOffset;

__shared__ int          aiLeafLeafFrontX[FRONT_UPDATE_SHARED_SIZE];
__shared__ int          aiLeafLeafFrontY[FRONT_UPDATE_SHARED_SIZE];

__shared__ int          aiNode0GreaterFrontX[FRONT_UPDATE_SHARED_SIZE];
__shared__ int          aiNode0GreaterFrontY[FRONT_UPDATE_SHARED_SIZE];

__shared__ int          aiNode1GreaterFrontX[FRONT_UPDATE_SHARED_SIZE];
__shared__ int          aiNode1GreaterFrontY[FRONT_UPDATE_SHARED_SIZE];

if(threadIdx.x == 0)
{
    uiInputFrontIdx = aiFrontIdx[blockIdx.x];
    uiOutputFrontIdx = 0;
    uiWorkQueueIdx = aiWork_queue_counts[blockIdx.x];

    iLeafLeafOffset = 0;
    iNode0GreaterOffset = 0;
    iNode1GreaterOffset = 0;
}
__syncthreads();

unsigned int uiThreadOffset = threadIdx.x;

while(uiThreadOffset < uiInputFrontIdx + FRONT_UPDATE_THREADS - (uiInputFrontIdx % FRONT_UPDATE_THREADS))
{
    if(uiThreadOffset < uiInputFrontIdx)
    {
        int2 bvttNode;

        aFront->getElement(bvttNode , blockIdx.x*FRONT_DEQUE_SIZE + uiThreadOffset);

        TreeNode node0 = tree[bvttNode.x];
        TreeNode node1 = tree[bvttNode.y];

        if(node0.isLeaf() && node1.isLeaf())
        {
            int iOffset = atomicAdd(&iLeafLeafOffset , 1);

            //Bank conflict source
            aiLeafLeafFrontX[iOffset] = bvttNode.x;
            aiLeafLeafFrontY[iOffset] = bvttNode.y;
            //End of bank conflict source
        }
        else if(node1.isLeaf() || (!node0.isLeaf() && (node0.bbox.getSize() > node1.bbox.getSize())))
        { // node0 is bigger. Subdivide it.
            int iOffset = atomicAdd(&iNode0GreaterOffset , 1);

            //Bank conflict source
            aiNode0GreaterFrontX[iOffset] = bvttNode.x;
            aiNode0GreaterFrontY[iOffset] = bvttNode.y;
            //End of bank conflict source
        }
        else
        { // node1 is bigger. Subdivide it.
            int iOffset = atomicAdd(&iNode1GreaterOffset , 1);

            //Bank conflict source
            aiNode1GreaterFrontX[iOffset] = bvttNode.x;
            aiNode1GreaterFrontY[iOffset] = bvttNode.y;
            //End of bank conflict source
        }
    }

    __syncthreads();

    /* ... */

    uiThreadOffset += uiNThreads;
    __syncthreads();
}
```

I want to know why the bank conflicts are ocurring. The only way I think conflicts could happen is if the accesses in different arrays that map to the same bank were serialized.

Comment: It is pretty hard to comment on bank conflicts without even knowing the dimensions of the shared memory arrays....

Comment: I have edited with the kernel call code and constants definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities. Further testing is required to choose which one is the culpit:

- The bank conflict is not occurring from the location you selected, but from the `atomicAdd` operations which also work on shared memory. I believe atomics on shmem can increase the internal conflict counters as well. (the belief is not tested!)
- You hit a situation where two or more warps are atomically increasing the same value - this might be a possibility on newer hardware which runs 2 or 4 warps at the same time. (testing is required to confirm or deny this as well). As a result, threads within one warp may actually get quite distant `iOffset` values and you end up having some random bank conflicts.

However, if either of the above is true, I woulndn't worry about the conflicts much. In the first case - `atomicAdd` hits your performance anyway. In the latter case, I wouldn't expect having greater than 2-way bank conflicts often. Unless you hit some really rare corner case....

Comment: I've already done a test to see if the conflicts are ocurring because of the atomics. I have commented all shared array accesses so just the atomics operations accessed shared memory. Nsight reported 0 bank conflicts in this case.

Comment: How did you do it? By moving aiLeafLeafFrontX (and other) arrays to global? Or just dropping it? Keep in mind that such changes can influence the warp scheduling and reduce bank conflicts elsewhere...

Comment: I just commented the code that accesses the shared arrays, leaving just the atomics that calculates the array offsets and run a Nsight CUDA analysis. For example:  
  
'    int iOffset = atomicAdd(&iLeafLeafOffset , 1);  
    //aiLeafLeafFrontX[iOffset] = bvttNode.x;  
    //aiLeafLeafFrontY[iOffset] = bvttNode.y;  '
  
I don't understand why warp scheduling can influence in the bank conflicts. My understanding is that conflicts are related with the array index which is not dependent on scheduling. Can you please explain it in more details?

Comment: Warp scheduling does not affect bank conflicts directly, but may influence the distribution of values of atomics. Also - if you just comment out a part of code, the compiler may detect that remaining code is redundant and remove much more that you think. In particular - if you never write to global memory, your kernel may reduce to an empty kernel.

Comment: You are right. The scheduling affects the ordering that threads do the atomics and can generate bank conflicts. I'll try a prefix-sum approach for better control on indices. I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks for the tips!